# How do I use Server-Side Includes in Webstorm?

Tags: html, apache, webstorm, ssi

I have a few .html files in a project I am working on for a class. All with the same header and footer. We are required to use SSI with Apache, but I am having trouble looking for a way to have my includes code acknowledged by WebStorm. To be honest, I'd be content with just a way to include the same code header by using just one line of code, but I'd rather not have to replace the code with SSI code in every page before I hand it in.

Comment: what problems using SSI in WebStorm have you faced? They are currently supported by built-in webserver (since WebStorm 10)

Comment: Wait, really? How come my .shtml file isn't being loaded in? I am using 
`<!--#include file="nav.shtml"-->`
with both my index.html file that is calling it and the nav.shtml in the same directory.